# What was the first time a "re-used booster" was used to put a payload into orbit?

Tags: falcon-9, space-shuttle, reuse, spaceflight-firsts, srb

In the excitement about SpaceX's Falcon recovery and relaunch development program, it's often forgotten in [articles like this one](http://www.floridatoday.com/story/tech/science/space/spacex/2017/03/28/ses-confident-spacex-rocket-can-deliver-second-time/99699862/) that reusable spacecraft were in regular use far back in the 20th century:

> SES this week hopes to see its SES-10 communications satellite become the first payload delivered to orbit by a rocket booster that has already completed an orbital launch.

If we specify that "rocket booster" means, precisely, *all the parts of the rocket which are involved in providing propellant and thrust at liftoff*, then this would seem to be correct.

If we relax our definition a bit to mean something like *any airframe with engines which is providing thrust at liftoff*, then [STS-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-2) would be the historic flight; *Columbia* carried a number of scientific experiments on its second orbital mission.

If delivering payload to orbit and *leaving it there* is a requirement, then some other shuttle flight would qualify.

Since the Shuttle external tanks were not reused, one could argue that none of the shuttle flights qualify, though I consider it disingenuous to consider the ET a dealbreaker while ignoring the Falcon 9 second stage entirely.

That leaves the shuttle SRBs, which could reasonably be argued to be part of "the rocket booster" in a way that the ET is not. The SRBs, however, were also recovered and rebuilt after launch.

Thus, my question is: **what was the first shuttle flight in which both the orbiter and the SRB casings were re-used hardware?**

For purposes of the question, the SRB wouldn't have to be 100% reused (if, say, nose cones were never reflown) as long as a large majority, say 75% of it was.

Comment: Would it be worth rewording the title to clarify that this is Shuttle-specific?

Comment: Current title is optimized for snarkiness.

Comment: I look forward to an answer to this question in hopes of it citing a good reference to SRB case segment history.  I know only of a history of the case segments flown on STS-135.

Comment: @organicmarble Dammit, I was counting on you to have the answer for this one.

Comment: I've seen references to such documents on nasaspaceflight.com but no actual links.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the SRBs where in fact different segments, which could or could not be reused together. The first reused SRB might as well be only made of some reused SRBs parts, and some new ones. Would it still qualify or do you want a 100% reused parts SRB?

Comment: 75% parts reused.

Comment: As you are mentioning STS-2: this was the first flight, where O-ring blow-by was observed. They are going to be used again on the SLS, but this time they will not be reused. That's quite a hint on how well it all worked.

You are also forgetting, that the SRBs were dismanteled and shipped back all the way to Utah. Only the steel casings were reused. 

SpaceX conducts an inspection and refuels on site. That is an entirely different category.

When you read about the space shuttle program, you will find that many decisions were political. SpaceX is not crippled by that.

Answer (score 4):

There is two answers to this question depending on the criteria.   If the criteria is first flight of a segment previously used, then the first actual "used" segment to fly was on STS-2 with the mid center segment on both the RH and LH booster from (DM-2) Development Motor 2.  Interestingly, the blow-by referred to on STS-2 occurred between this used segment and the new aft segment.
The first previously flown segment to make its second flight was STS-11(41B), the LH mid center segment.   The second known occurrence of blow-by in the program was on this joint.  Interesting as well.   By the time of the Challenger accident, 75% of the segments flown were "used"

Comment: Unfortunately, no single good source exists for the stacking information.   I have developed a spreadsheet which I am sure is 100% accurate for the first 25 flights.     The source was former MTI engineers and managers who have been working with me on the stacking issue.  The real  issue with this data is that NASA did not  have direct access to it in 1985.   It was locked away in the VAB and under the direct control of a contractor, Lockheed Space Operations

Comment: The SRB segments were not interchangeable after they were filled with propellant at MTI.   The aerodynamics restrictions  of STS flight envelope meant that the SRB  thrust profile had to essentially "throttle" up,down and back up.   This meant that the Fwd segment had a star configuration in it, the center segment had a oval shaped pour thicker at the top thinner at the base and the aft segment had thinnest propellant depth of the 3 segments.      Once segments were poured at MTI  they were locked into a position on the SRB.  This came into play at the FRR on 12/5/85 with STS-51L segment swap.